# Is this efficient and should I be using encapsulation in a better way?

Tags: c#, encapsulation

Here is the code. Please see my questions at the bottom of this post.

```
public partial class myClass : Other.Class
    {
        long check1parameter = CurrentSession.CurrentFile.ID;

        protected override void EnquiryLoaded(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
        {
            disableFields();
        }
        private void disableFields() 
        {
            if (checkEverything()) {
                EnquiryForm.GetControl("Status").Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        public bool check1_method(long check1parameter) {
            bool Check1 = false;
            string stringToCheck = check1parameter.ToString();
            if (stringToCheck.Contains("something")) {
                    Check1 = true;
                }
            return Check1;
        }

        public bool checkEverything() {
            bool roleCheck = CurrentSession.CurrentUser.IsInRoles("RequiredRole");
            bool check1 = check1_method(check1parameter);
            bool checkEverything = false;
            if (roleCheck && check1) {
                checkEverything = true;
            } 
            return checkEverything;
        }
        //other methods
    }
```

The code is to check that someone has a role and also that a string contains a bit of info and then disable a field. I have simplified this from the actual code to outline the key points. Although the intention is only to run these simple checks and disable a field, I thought it best to create individual methods for these tasks so they can be expanded later on.

I do get an object reference error with `long check1parameter` being defined in that position. It was in `check1_method()` and worked correctly but it's something I'd like to be declared once and used across multiple areas if possible.

I also want to pass parameters\variables to `check1_method` rather than declaring them inside it. What's the best way to approach making `check1parameter` available to all methods in this partial class? It refers to another class which is linked to `Other.Class` in some way.

My main question is - how do I make this as efficient as possible and should I be using `private` in place of `public` anywhere here? I'm still very new to C# and haven't quite figured out encapsulation yet, so please go easy on me! :)

Comment: `check1parameter` is a long, why are you comparing it with the string `"something"`?

Comment: Although it's a long, it occasionally contains text and gets converted to a string. I am checking for 'something' being part of the string (notice it's converted to a string just above - `stringToCheck = check1parameter.ToString()`

Comment: A long is a numerical type, so it can only contain an integer, do you mean to be using a `char[]` or `byte[]`? Or am I being confused, that you're not actually comparing the string literal `"Something"` but you mean something along the lines of `"123456"`?

Comment: `something` can be replaced with any text/number. I'm not comparing the literal word, just checking for presence of something like `abc123`

Comment: Well that's what I'm saying, `check1parameter` can never contain `"abc123"`. If you try to assign a sring to `check1parameter`, it will throw an error. If you want it to be flexible, maybe you should be declaring it as a `var` or `object`?

Comment: I've now changed my code (not the one here) to another value that I can check which is already a string. But I get what you're saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myClass` doesn't need to be declared as partial unless you intend to continue implementing it in a different file.

When using a simple if statement they can be removed, for example you could write:

```
public partial class myClass : Other.Class
    {
        long check1parameter = CurrentSession.CurrentFile.ID;

        protected override void EnquiryLoaded(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
        {
            disableFields();
        }
        private void disableFields() 
        {
            EnquiryForm.GetControl("Status").Enabled = checkEverything();
        }

        public bool check1_method(long check1parameter) {
            return check1parameter.ToString().Contains("something");
        }

        public bool checkEverything() {
            bool roleCheck = CurrentSession.CurrentUser.IsInRoles("RequiredRole");
            bool check1 = check1_method(check1parameter);

            return (roleCheck && check1);
        }
        //other methods
    }
```

In order to save yourself from declaring unnecessary bools. Beyond that you'd be sacrificing readability for fewer lines.

When it comes to public vs private, it's good practice to always specify private unless you need to access it from outside of the class. At a glance, `disableFields()` should probably be public, and `check1_method()` and `checkEverything()` be private.

EDIT:
Also, if `check1parameter` is instantiated globally to `myClass`, then you don't need to pass it in as a parameter to `check1_methods()`

Comment: Removing the if statement in disableField isn't logically equivalent. Your code will update the status everytime disable field is called. The original code will only enable the field if checkEverything is true.

Comment: @PaulTsai True, it's just that the function disableFields() implies that the field might be disabled. If @jbab8 intends to use encapsulation and is still setting `EnquiryForm.GetControl("Status").Enabled` to false elsewhere, then it's defeating the purpose of having the function in the first place. So that's why I took some liberties there.

Comment: The `status` field is indeed set to false, earlier in the `disableFields()` method. The idea being that unless all the checks result in true, it's disabled. I'll try the changes you suggested but could I couple them with the changes suggested in the other answer about using properties for maximum efficiency (guessing here..)?

Comment: @jbab8 Yes, you could effectively do `EnquiryForm.GetControl("Status").Enabled = checkEverything;` according to Paul's answer. Generally as a rule of thumb, wherever you set a bool to false, use a simple if statement and then set it based on that, you can just set the bool's value to the comparison you're using in the if statement.

Comment: Thanks, I've probably reduced the code by about 60% using your code instead! I can't mark both as the answer but as I've used more of your solution I will give you the rewards :)

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided looks ok. I've made a couple of changes, mostly code aesthetics. The main one is to make the 2 check methods into properties.

```
public partial class myClass : Other.Class
{
    long check1parameter = CurrentSession.CurrentFile.ID;

    protected override void EnquiryLoaded(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        disableFields();
    }

    private void disableFields()
    {
        if (checkEverything)
        {
            EnquiryForm.GetControl("Status").Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    // the parameter name was the same as a variable in the class
    // renamed to avoid confusion
    public bool check1_method
    {
        get {return check1parameter.ToString().Contains("something");}
    }

    public bool checkEverything
    {
        get { return CurrentSession.CurrentUser.IsInRoles("RequiredRole") 
            && check1_method; }
    }
    //other methods
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks a lot neater. What advantage is there by using properties instead of the way I did it?

Comment: @jbab8 as Paul mentioned, it's mainly aesthetics. There is some overhead by using a function, but it's negligible in the first place, and the compiler would probably output the same machine code in either circumstance; so it comes down to readability and preference.

Comment: @jbab8 On a conceptual level, it helps reinforce the design in your mind. A property is an aspect/member/variable(s) of a class, a method is an action. Whether or not you should check something is predicated on the state of some variables, not really an action. That should help determine whether something is a property or not.